# How can I count the number of attributes of an element in Selenium Python?

Tags: python-2.7, selenium-webdriver

Having the following HTML code:

```
<span class="warning" id ="warning">WARNING:</span>
```

For an object accessible by XPAth:

```
.//*[@id='unlink']/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/span
```

How can one count its attributes (*class, id*) by means of Selenium WebDriver + Python 2.7, without actually knowing their names?

I'm expecting something like count = 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it! This should work for div, span, img, p and many other basic elements.

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath) #Locate the element.

outerHTML = element.get_attribute("outerHTML") #Get its HTML
innerHTML = element.get_attribute("innerHTML") #See where its inner content starts

if len(innerHTML) > 0: # Let's make this work for input as well
    innerHTML = innerHTML.strip() # Strip whitespace around inner content
    toTrim = outerHTML.index(innerHTML) # Get the index of the first part, before the inner content
    # In case of moste elements, this is what we care about
    rightString = outerHTML[:toTrim]
else:
    # We seem to have something like <input class="bla" name="blabla"> which is good
    rightString = outerHTML
# Ie: <span class="something" id="somethingelse">

strippedString = rightString.strip() # Remove whitespace, if any
rightTrimmedString = strippedString.rstrip('<>') #
leftTrimmedString = rightTrimmedString.lstrip('</>') # Remove the <, >, /, chars.
rawAttributeArray = leftTrimmedString.split(' ') # Create an array of:
# [span, id = "something", class="somethingelse"]

curatedAttributeArray = [] # This is where we put the good values
iterations = len(rawAttributeArray)

for x in range(iterations):
    if "=" in rawAttributeArray[x]: #We want the attribute="..." pairs
        curatedAttributeArray.append(rawAttributeArray[x]) # and add them to a list

numberOfAttributes = len(curatedAttributeArray) #Let's see what we got
print numberOfAttributes # There we go
```

I hope this helps.

Thanks,
R.

P.S. This could be further enhanced, like stripping whitespace together with <, > or /.

Answer (score 0):

It's not going to be easy.

Every element has a series of implicit attributes as well as the ones explicitly defined (for example selected, disabled, etc).  As a result the only way I can think to do it would be to get a reference to the parent and then use a JavaScript executor to get the innerHTML:

```
document.getElementById('{ID of element}').innerHTML
```

You would then have to parse what is returned by innerHTML to extract out individual elements and then once you have isolated the element that you are interested in you would again have to  parse that element to extract out a list of attributes.

Comment: If I do something like:

`elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
print elem.get_attribute("outerHTML")
print elem.get_attribute("innerHTML")`

I get:

`<span class="warning">WARNING:</span>` and 
`WARNING:`

So, perhaps some Python REGEX combined with elem.get_attribute("outerHTML") might do the trick?

Comment: Good point, I didn't think of using outerHTML (which would make sense as it will give you the element you currently have selected, DOH).